# Linux at command won't run the job in the past, lists it for tomorrow

Tags: linux, at

I am trying to run a series of commands using `at` in about half an hour. However, `at` will either schedule it for tomorrow (if I don't specify today's date).

If I do specify the date, it says it won't schedule it in the past.

I imagine this has something to do with daylight savings time. How do I work around this?

What about if I used cron, would `cron` handle it correctly?

Comment: Check your current time before try to schedule it

Comment: Current time when running `date` shows correctly.

Comment: And what is the exact syntax you try to exec?

Comment: I found my error. Does at use 24 hour syntax, so 3PM is "15:00"

Comment: Yes, it use 24h format :)

Comment: well, looks like that was my problem I can either to 15:00 or `at 3pm`